# LayerSwitcher() not working with Group Layers in Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I created a layer group. then previewed the layer using the GeoServer Layer Previewer and it all worked nicely.But Layer switcher is not working properly.layer switcher doesn't show any layers
Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>OpenLayers map preview</title>
    <!-- Import OL CSS, auto import does not work with our minified OL.js build -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css"/>
    <!-- Basic CSS definitions -->
    <style type="text/css">
        /* General settings */
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
        }
        /* Toolbar styles */
        #toolbar {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
            display: none;
        }

        #toolbar ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #toolbar ul li {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 1em;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }

        #toolbar ul li a {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: smaller;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #toolbar ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #toolbar ul li * {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        /* The map and the location bar */
        #map {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            width: 700px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 528px;
        }

        #location {
            float: right;
        }

        #options {
            position: absolute;
            left: 13px;
            top: 7px;
            z-index: 3000;
        }

        /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */
        table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 90%;
            padding: .2em .1em;
        }

        table.featureInfo th {
            padding: .2em .2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #eee;
        }

        table.featureInfo td {
            background: #fff;
        }

        table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
            background: #eee;
        }

        table.featureInfo caption {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: .2em .2em;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Import OpenLayers, reduced, wms read only version -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var untiled;
        var tiled;
        var pureCoverage = false;
        // pink tile avoidance
        OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 5;
        // make OL compute scale according to WMS spec
        OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 25.4 / 0.28;

        function init(){
            // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
            // and default to jpeg format
            format = 'image/png';
            if(pureCoverage) {
                document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
                format = "image/jpeg";
            }

            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                168000, 239999.99999999962,
                176000.0001000001, 245000
            );
            var options = {
                controls: [],
                maxExtent: bounds,
                maxResolution: 31.25000039062536,
                projection: "EPSG:5234",
                units: 'm'
            };
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

            // setup tiled layer
            tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Geoserver layers - Tiled", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geoportaltest/wms",
                {
                    "STYLES": '',
                    "LAYERS": 'geoproject',
                    format: format
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx : {'EPSG:5234' : false}
                } 
            );

            // setup single tiled layer
            untiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Geoserver layers - Untiled", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geoportaltest/wms",
                {
                    "STYLES": '',
                    "LAYERS": 'geoproject',
                    format: format
                },
                {
                   singleTile: true, 
                   ratio: 1, 
                   isBaseLayer: true,
                   yx : {'EPSG:5234' : false}
                } 
            );

    //tiled.setVisibility(false);
       // untiled.setVisibility(false);

            map.addLayers([untiled, tiled]);

            // build up all controls
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
                position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)
            }));

            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());

            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scale')));
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({element: $('location')}));



            map.zoomToExtent(bounds);


            // wire up the option button
            var options = document.getElementById("options");
            options.onclick = toggleControlPanel;

            // support GetFeatureInfo
            map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
                document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
                var params = {
                    REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                    EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                    BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                    SERVICE: "WMS",
                    INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
                    QUERY_LAYERS: map.layers[0].params.LAYERS,
                    FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                    "Layers": 'geoproject',
                    WIDTH: map.size.w,
                    HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                    format: format,
                    styles: map.layers[0].params.STYLES,
                    srs: map.layers[0].params.SRS};

                // handle the wms 1.3 vs wms 1.1 madness
                if(map.layers[0].params.VERSION == "1.3.0") {
                    params.version = "1.3.0";
                    params.j = parseInt(e.xy.x);
                    params.i = parseInt(e.xy.y);
                } else {
                    params.version = "1.1.1";
                    params.x = parseInt(e.xy.x);
                    params.y = parseInt(e.xy.y);
                }

                // merge filters
                if(map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER != null) {
                    params.cql_filter = map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER;
                } 
                if(map.layers[0].params.FILTER != null) {
                    params.filter = map.layers[0].params.FILTER;
                }
                if(map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID) {
                    params.featureid = map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID;
                }
                OpenLayers.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geoportaltest/wms", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);
                OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
            });
        }

        // sets the HTML provided into the nodelist element
        function setHTML(response){
            document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = response.responseText;
        };

        // shows/hide the control panel
        function toggleControlPanel(event){
            var toolbar = document.getElementById("toolbar");
            if (toolbar.style.display == "none") {
                toolbar.style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                toolbar.style.display = "none";
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
            map.updateSize()
        }

        // Tiling mode, can be 'tiled' or 'untiled'
        function setTileMode(tilingMode){
            if (tilingMode == 'tiled') {
                untiled.setVisibility(false);
                tiled.setVisibility(true);
                map.setBaseLayer(tiled);
            }
            else {
                untiled.setVisibility(true);
                tiled.setVisibility(false);
                map.setBaseLayer(untiled);
            }
        }

        // Transition effect, can be null or 'resize'
        function setTransitionMode(transitionEffect){
            if (transitionEffect === 'resize') {
                tiled.transitionEffect = transitionEffect;
                untiled.transitionEffect = transitionEffect;
            }
            else {
                tiled.transitionEffect = null;
                untiled.transitionEffect = null;
            }
        }

        // changes the current tile format
        function setImageFormat(mime){
            // we may be switching format on setup
            if(tiled == null)
              return;

            tiled.mergeNewParams({
                format: mime
            });
            untiled.mergeNewParams({
                format: mime
            });
            /*
            var paletteSelector = document.getElementById('paletteSelector')
            if (mime == 'image/jpeg') {
                paletteSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
                setPalette('');
                paletteSelector.disabled = true;
            }
            else {
                paletteSelector.disabled = false;
            }
            */
        }

        // sets the chosen style
        function setStyle(style){
            // we may be switching style on setup
            if(tiled == null)
              return;

            tiled.mergeNewParams({
                styles: style
            });
            untiled.mergeNewParams({
                styles: style
            });
        }

        // sets the chosen WMS version
        function setWMSVersion(wmsVersion){
            // we may be switching style on setup
            if(wmsVersion == null)
              return;

            if(wmsVersion == "1.3.0") {
               origin = map.maxExtent.bottom + ',' + map.maxExtent.left;
            } else {
               origin = map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom;
            }

            tiled.mergeNewParams({
                version: wmsVersion,
                tilesOrigin : origin
            });
            untiled.mergeNewParams({
                version: wmsVersion
            });
        }

        function setAntialiasMode(mode){
            tiled.mergeNewParams({
                format_options: 'antialias:' + mode
            });
            untiled.mergeNewParams({
                format_options: 'antialias:' + mode
            });
        }

        function setPalette(mode){
            if (mode == '') {
                tiled.mergeNewParams({
                    palette: null
                });
                untiled.mergeNewParams({
                    palette: null
                });
            }
            else {
                tiled.mergeNewParams({
                    palette: mode
                });
                untiled.mergeNewParams({
                    palette: mode
                });
            }
        }

        function setWidth(size){
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
            var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

            if (size == "auto") {
                // reset back to the default value
                mapDiv.style.width = null;
                wrapper.style.width = null;
            }
            else {
                mapDiv.style.width = size + "px";
                wrapper.style.width = size + "px";
            }
            // notify OL that we changed the size of the map div
            map.updateSize();
        }

        function setHeight(size){
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');

            if (size == "auto") {
                // reset back to the default value
                mapDiv.style.height = null;
            }
            else {
                mapDiv.style.height = size + "px";
            }
            // notify OL that we changed the size of the map div
            map.updateSize();
        }

        function updateFilter(){
            if(pureCoverage)
              return;

            var filterType = document.getElementById('filterType').value;
            var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;

            // by default, reset all filters
            var filterParams = {
                filter: null,
                cql_filter: null,
                featureId: null
            };
            if (OpenLayers.String.trim(filter) != "") {
                if (filterType == "cql") 
                    filterParams["cql_filter"] = filter;
                if (filterType == "ogc") 
                    filterParams["filter"] = filter;
                if (filterType == "fid") 
                    filterParams["featureId"] = filter;
            }
            // merge the new filter definitions
            mergeNewParams(filterParams);
        }

        function resetFilter() {
            if(pureCoverage)
              return;

            document.getElementById('filter').value = "";
            updateFilter();
        }

        function mergeNewParams(params){
            tiled.mergeNewParams(params);
            untiled.mergeNewParams(params);
        }

          // add a layer switcher control
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('layerswitcher')}));
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>WMS version:</a>
                <select id="wmsVersionSelector" onchange="setWMSVersion(value)">
                    <option value="1.1.1">1.1.1</option>
                    <option value="1.3.0">1.3.0</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Tiling:</a>
                <select id="tilingModeSelector" onchange="setTileMode(value)">
                    <option value="untiled">Single tile</option>
                    <option value="tiled">Tiled</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Transition effect:</a>
                <select id="transitionEffectSelector" onchange="setTransitionMode(value)">
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    <option value="resize">Resize</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Antialias:</a>
                <select id="antialiasSelector" onchange="setAntialiasMode(value)">
                    <option value="full">Full</option>
                    <option value="text">Text only</option>
                    <option value="none">Disabled</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Format:</a>
                <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setImageFormat(value)">
                    <option value="image/png">PNG 24bit</option>
                    <option value="image/png8">PNG 8bit</option>
                    <option value="image/gif">GIF</option>
                    <option id="jpeg" value="image/jpeg">JPEG</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Styles:</a>
                <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setStyle(value)">
                    <option value="">Default</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <!-- Commented out for the moment, some code needs to be extended in 
                 order to list the available palettes
            <li>
                <a>Palette:</a>
                <select id="paletteSelector" onchange="setPalette(value)">
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    <option value="safe">Web safe</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            -->
            <li>
                <a>Width/Height:</a>
                <select id="widthSelector" onchange="setWidth(value)">
                    <!--
                    These values come from a statistics of the viewable area given a certain screen area
                    (but have been adapted a litte, simplified numbers, added some resolutions for wide screen)
                    You can find them here: http://www.evolt.org/article/Real_World_Browser_Size_Stats_Part_II/20/2297/
                    --><option value="auto">Auto</option>
                    <option value="600">600</option>
                    <option value="750">750</option>
                    <option value="950">950</option>
                    <option value="1000">1000</option>
                    <option value="1200">1200</option>
                    <option value="1400">1400</option>
                    <option value="1600">1600</option>
                    <option value="1900">1900</option>
                </select>
                <select id="heigthSelector" onchange="setHeight(value)">
                    <option value="auto">Auto</option>
                    <option value="300">300</option>
                    <option value="400">400</option>
                    <option value="500">500</option>
                    <option value="600">600</option>
                    <option value="700">700</option>
                    <option value="800">800</option>
                    <option value="900">900</option>
                    <option value="1000">1000</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Filter:</a>
                <select id="filterType">
                    <option value="cql">CQL</option>
                    <option value="ogc">OGC</option>
                    <option value="fid">FeatureID</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" size="80" id="filter"/>
                <img id="updateFilterButton" src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/img/east-mini.png" onClick="updateFilter()" title="Apply filter"/>
                <img id="resetFilterButton" src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/img/cancel.png" onClick="resetFilter()" title="Reset filter"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="map">
        <img id="options" title="Toggle options toolbar" src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/options.png"/>
    </div></br>
       <div id="layerswitcher" class="olControlLayerSwitcher"><img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/img/layer-switcher-maximize.png" style="position: relative; width: 18px; height: 18px;"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="location">location</div>
        <div id="scale">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nodelist">
        <em>Click on the map to get feature info</em>
    </div>
</body>
```

f

Where am I going wrong?